# About the Numbers of Dummy Variables

Tags: regression, categorical-data

I have a question on the choice of dummies in categorical regression. If there are 4 categories, can I just choose 2 dummy variables to represent them in the following way:
Category-Z1,Z2
c1-1,0
c2-0,1
c3-0,0
c4-1,1
If can't, I would like to know why the "1,1" can't be accepted... Data rookie just really confused about this. I found that the experiences on the internet almost are based on the "k categories, k-1 dummies" principle. Many thanks if you could explain about this!!

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the sum at the heart of the logistic regression: If you chose two dummy variables $Z_1, Z_2$, that sum would include something like $\beta_1 Z_1 + \beta_2 Z_2$ with the betas your estimated parameters. Assuming you encoded your 4 categories as described, you would get:

- $c_1$: $\beta_1$ (because $Z_1 = 1, Z_2$ = 0)
- $c_2$: $\beta_2$
- $c_3$: $0$
- $c_4$: $\beta_1 + \beta_2$

Therefore, baked into your choice of encoding would be that the effect of category 4 is the same as the effects from category 1 and 2 combined. That's normally not what we want and therefore we need a third dummy variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what those dummy variables actually are.

If your categories correspond to one dimension (for example, the color of a car which can be Black, Red, Green, Yellow) or if your categories correspond to two dimensions (for instance, the origin of the car which can be Japanese or American and the color of the car which can be Black or Red).

In the first case, you cannot use an interaction of your two dummies, but 1 dummy for each color (omitting one category which will be the constant - or all 4 dummies if you omit the constant).

In the second case, you can interact your dummies if your interpretation is "I want to know what the effect of a Black American car on, say, its price is, as opposed to a Red Japanese car, or a Red American car. In that case, I suggest you look at the interpretation of interactions of dummy variables.

Comment: Thanks! That's so clear!!

Comment: In that case, you can accept the answer.